# Cannot add extensions to GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, installation

I have installed apache tomcat 7 and successfully deployed Geoserver 2.7.  However whenever I copy an extension .jar file into WEB-INF/lib and try and restart geoserver using the tomcat html manager application it fails to start, and will not start until I reset my machine, delete the new .jar file and then start geoserver.

I have downloaded the latest version of geoserver 2.7 SNAPSHOT  and am using the latest 2.7 SNAPSHOT builds of the extensions.

The etxensions I am most interested in are the WPS and geopackage extensions.  http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/installing.html

I have left it for up to 15 minutes, which I would have thought was long enough.

Has anybody successfully added extensions to geoserver, or could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you get here the error text?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any error text in the tomcat manager.  It just hangs.  Can you point me towards which logs might have some information?  Should I search the geoserver or the tomcat logs?  It seems to happen no matter which extension I try and add.

Comment: you might need to assign (chown) the .jar file's owner as apache:tomcat or change access permissions

Comment: deploy another project to tomcat root, and then copy extension to "WEB-INF/lib". if the new project running, then look at geoserver log, Otherwise look at tomcat log.

Comment: I don't think i can chown the .jar file as I am running windows.  Morteza, do you mean another instance of geoserver 2.7?

Comment: These are the entries from the geoserver log when I try and restart it from the tomcat manager after copying the colormap extension (http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/geoserver-2.7-SNAPSHOT-colormap-plugin.zip) into the WEB-INF\lib folder:
http://tny.cz/d2e3327f

Comment: Perhaps you aren't waiting long enough? Those messages are just tomcat shutting down. It can take a couple of minutes for a full restart, especially if geoserver isn't the only thing installed. Also, are you installing just the jar, or all of the dependencies that the extension needs? Also, please edit the question (including telling us which extension(s)), instead of putting those details into the comments where they're about to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I will leave it overnight tonight and see if it works.

Comment: GeoServer is so simple and fast to install that I would do an experimental installation with the zipped Jetty version to some other port than the default 8080 and with manual start. I would put the program and data_dir to anywhere else than under Program Files. If 2.7 fails try also with 2.6.x. It may not have the extension you need but at least you can gather some more knowledge about the issue.

Comment: 15 minutes is more than long enough. There was some recent work on geopackage, which might have caused a regression. Does just WPS work? Lots of people have added extensions, but you aren't giving us much to go on without a full description of your debugging so far or the logs.

Comment: I am sorry, I am pretty new to this.  I have not been able to add any extension at all without tomcat and geoserver hanging when I try and restart it.

Comment: Additionally, it is a bit confusing that there seem to be two repositories for extensions: opengeo (http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/) and boundlessgeo (http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/master/ext-2015-01-14/).  The boundlessgeo wps plugin has more files, but the opengeo repository is the one with the geopackage plugin as well.  Either way I tried the boundlessgeo wps plugin this morning , and it does the same thing.  Copy it into the lib folder, restart geoserver, and tomcat manager hangs.

Comment: I ended up rolling a fresh VM with nothing but windows, apache tomcat, java 8 and geoserver, and the installations install correctly and everything seems to run OK.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to fix the issues I was having on my local machine.  I rolled a new VM with Windows 7, java 8, tomcat 8 and geoserver, and the extensions installed fine and everything seems to be running OK.